# Using argument names instead of indexes in custom annotation fields

Tags: java, spring-el

I am currently using a custom annotation to accept some fields which will be mapped to a value in the method's argument.
This works fine but is there a way I could pass in the argument name instead of the index?

For example, pass in:

key="name" instead of key="[0]" (Also tried key="#name" which ends up as null)

The following example works. I am just looking for a way to pass in the argument name to make it more readable instead of an index.

My Custom Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Sampling {
    String[] keys();
}
```

My Method being annotated:

```
@Sampling(keys = {"[0]"})
public Object get(String sample){
    return null;
}
```

The related Aspect which gets called when a method is annotated as @Sampling:

```
@Around("@annotation(sampling)")
public Object get(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Sampling sampling) throws Throwable {

    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();

    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    for(String key : sampling.keys()){
        Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(key);

        // This is the line with issue. If I had used index like keys = {"[0]"} , 
        // this would get the value of String sample in the methods argument as expected. 
        // Using the argument name throws error and using hash tag before it outputs as null. 
        String value = (String)expression.getValue(args);


        // some other logics
    }
}
```